# Plugin could not be deleted due to an error: Unable to locate WordPress Plugin directory

Tags: directory

I have moved my Wordpress site to a new host, because of performance problems on the old host.

I have updated wp-config.php with the new host's values, but when I try to delete a plugin from wp-admin, I receive

> "Plugin could not be deleted due to an error: Unable to locate
>   WordPress Plugin directory."

I have defined FTP_BASE correctly in wp-config.php.

Where else would I need to set the value of local file system root folder?

Comment: Should we guess the plugin name?

Comment: You could try.  This error is not dependent on the plugin - it affects all plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Create separate FTP user for WordPress and set your installation directory as FTP root. Or try to change it for existing user.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using vsftpd, you can specify local root to your WP directory, aka:

```
sudo vim /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf
```

and add the line:

```
local_root=/path/to/your/wordpress/
```

and restart vsftpd for changes to take effect.